# Rest API Authentication for widget request

Tags: node.js, security, authentication

I have a widget which users integrate on their website and the request from the widget comes to our nodeJS backend. I want to implement auth mechanism so that I will verify those requests and then only process it.

PS - JWT token will not be helpful as anyone can check network tab and send requests using Postman or any API client

Comment: Have you used Google Maps? Google provides a widget that you can put on your site, but you need to initialize it with an API key. An API key is only good on a particular site (origin). This does not prevent clients from talking directly to the API, but it does prevent Customer A from stealing the widget directly from Customer B's site and copying it into their own.

Comment: yeah exactly so want to do something so that users of that website will not talk with APIs directly by checking network tabs and hitting requests using API client.